# Including HTML Files in Closure Compiler

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library

The Closure Compiler works great on .js files; something I can't figure out however is how to pass .html files to compiler.jar so that all references are preserved.  Also, is it possible to pass .html files to the compiler to obfuscate `<script>...</script>` sections?

Many thanks, Kate.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible. Using `goog.exportSymbol` and `goog.exportProperty` to export the methods and properties you need to call from the html is the best way I know of to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closure Compiler can not compile javascript embedded in HTML (https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/faq#tags)

As burnttoast11 mentioned, use exporting to preserve javascript object names you need to use in the HTML javascript (https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#export).

Lastly, the more code you can move out of HTML and into separate Javascript files, the more work closure compiler can do for you.